# Struts 2 - URL tag not going through dispatcher

Tags: jsp, struts2, dispatcher

I'm new to struts.

I made an index.jsp page that has an href to an action that loads another JSP. **I simply want to have a link that a user can click to go to another JSP.**

I am getting the error :  `The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet`

Please see this imgur album for screenshots of the project/code:

[Link to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XlzK.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't link to jsp directly, instead create an action and link to it.

Comment: You can make any link to any page that has mapped by the Struts filter without any problem.

Comment: My login page is mapped to the filter, and uses struts form tags. The filter error says that the request must go through an action before coming to this page. In essence, I have to process an action before getting to the login page. The problem is, I have no idea how to do this. I suppose I could do an html page with a button that goes to an action that returns this page, but that seems absurd. I've gone through login page tutorial after login page tutorial, and none of them address this issue. Is it a glassfish thing? I am so lost.

Comment: Also, doing <a href ="actionName.action" ></a>doesn't work. <a href="pageName.jsp"></a> throws the filter error (because it uses struts-tags.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all–many (all?) S2 tags expect to be called only on pages displayed as the result of executing an action.

If you are linking from one bare JSP to another just use a link tag; there's no S2 functionality involved at all, and no need to involve S2 tags.

It should be rare to hit a "bare" JSP page in an S2 app at all. At most you might have a landing page that redirects to an action.

Comment: The point is that I am trying to link to another page. How does one do this? I linked to the action for that page, so I could avoid this error, but it doesn't work. I am getting the same error. I can't get to a page without an action. But the embedded action link throws this error. This will recursively fail. Is there any way to put a link in a JSP that will take you to another JSP in your project?

Comment: Nevermind, I think this breaks the MVC framework use.

Comment: @KimberlyL You most certainly *can* get to any page via a normal anchor tag if you have the URL correct, whether it's an action or a JSP. The S2 URL tags are only useful if you need S2 functionality, and won't function on JSPs not reached through an action.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the code to your `web.xml`:

```
<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping> 
<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```